# Kendo UI Window with Bootstrap Color Picker, Window Always On Top

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I'm having an issue using the Kendo UI Window to show an editing form that also has a Bootstrap Color Picker on it.  The issue is that the window always shows on top of the color picker and covers half of it.  If the window is set up as a modal window, you can't touch the color picker, but if the modal setting is set to false, you can change the color, but you'll only see half of the window.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the color picker to show on top of the Kendo UI Window?  I've attached a screen shot to show the issue.  Thanks.

For further details:

There's a grid on the parent page that has a button that opens the Kendo UI window, which then loads a partial view.  The partial view has the editing controls in it along with the color picker.  The color picker is set on a span tag:

```
    <span class="color" data-color="@Model.LabelColor" data-color-format="hex" id="BreedingColorPicker">
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LabelColor)
      <span class="add-on"><i class="label_color_box" style="background-color: @Model.LabelColor">&nbsp;</i></span>
    </span>
```

[image: Bootstrap color picker shows behind Kendo UI Window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an easier fix than I thought, just took a while to find.  The issue with this was determining the z-indexes for the elements.  The Kendo UI Window had a z-index of 10007, which was much higher than what I was trying to set the z-index to on the color picker.  The solution I came up with was to go into the bootstrap colorpicker.css file and add the z-index to it manually.  For anyone else that might be having a similar issue, just make the following change to the colorpicker.css file:

```
.colorpicker {
     *zoom: 1;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     padding: 4px;
     min-width: 120px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     z-index: 12000; /* Added to make sure the color picker shows up on top of the Kendo UI Windows */
}
```